# Make sure he painted the room

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense, american-english, past-perfect, british-english

Can we use "make sure" with past tense or past participle tense eg "make sure he painted the room" "make sure he had already painted the room when you left for london yesterday"

Comment: Your second sentence doesn't make sense because you're using the imperative (i.e., giving a command) in the past - you can't order someone to change history!  You can, however, ask a question about the past: "**Did you** make sure he had already painted the room when you left for London yesterday?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use *sure* with the past tense.
*Make sure he painted the room.*
You are telling someone to verify (in the present) a fact about the past - find out whether he painted the room.

You can also use it about the future, asking someone to make something happen:
*Make sure he paints the room.*